# How can I add custom header s to my nextjs app?

Tags: next.js, vercel, custom-headers

I am wishing to add X-Robots-Tag to prevent my website from being indexed by search engines.
I have found a way to do that in [Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/guides/are-vercel-preview-deployment-indexed-by-search-engines#x-robots-tag-header)

The issue that I am facing is how to inject that alongside with the existing configuration in my *next.config.js* file.
That's the current content of the file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const webpack=(config)=> {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
  })

  return config
}
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  webpack:webpack,
  images: {
    domains: ['images.unsplash.com','images.prismic.io'],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And those are the configs that I wish to add :
`

```js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    const headers = [];
      headers.push({
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'X-Robots-Tag',
            value: 'noindex',
          },
        ],
        source: '/:path*',
      });
    return headers;
  },
 };
```

If anyone of you have an idea I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const webpack = (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack']
    });

    return config;
};
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    webpack: webpack,
    images: {
        domains: ['images.unsplash.com', 'images.prismic.io'],
    },

    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/:path*',
                headers: [
                    {
                        key: 'X-Robots-Tag',
                        value: 'noindex'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```